# The Console Log Display issue

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am taking a Web Development course online in which, I am following along with my instructor.

The problem is that when she uses `console.log`, it shows on her the console. However when I use `console.log`, it shows `undefined`.

```js
var output = [];

function fizzBuzz() {
    if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
        output.push("FizzBuzz");

        if (count % 3 === 0) {
            output.push("Fizz");
        } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("Buzz")
        } else {
            output.push(count);
        }

        count++;
        console.log(output);
    }
}

fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: hey, can you add some code, In which it is showing undefined?

Comment: Where does the `count` variable come from?

Comment: can you describe what is the default value of `count` this is a mystery

Answer (score 1):

It means that the variable you are using in console.log() is not defined.

Did you try console.log("Test"); ?

Perhaps I could be of more help if you show your code

Comment: If you are not sure about the concept visit: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp

Comment: var output = []

function fizzBuzz()  {
 
if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
  output.push("FizzBuzz");

if (count % 3 === 0) {

output.push("Fizz");

}
else if (count % 5 === 0) {
  output.push("Buzz")


} else {
 output.push(count);
}
 count++;


 console.log(output);


}
}

Comment: where is this count defined?
The problem is not with console.log but with the execution of code. Perhaps your count is not defined and initialized properly. Anyways your if condition is not running and nothing is being pushed in the output array that is why console.log(output) shows nothing

Comment: You can pass count as the parameter of function and try with different values you will definitely get something in console.log()

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not problem in your code if we define the `count`.

What happens sometimes, when a var is undefined then next lines becomes senseless for the compiler.

so if we define `count` then everything will be running fine
let's see following code snippet.

```js
var output = [];
var count = 0;
function fizzBuzz() {
    if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
        output.push("FizzBuzz");

        if (count % 3 === 0) {
            output.push("Fizz");
        } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("Buzz")
        } else {
            output.push(count);
        }

        count++;
        console.log(output);
    }
}

fizzBuzz();
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you write something between the brackets.

```
console.log("HEYYY!!");
```

will display HEYYY!!

```
console.log();
```

will just display undefined.

It would be helpful if you post the code here.

Comment: Wouldn't the first one complain about incorrect syntax and the second one just print nothing?

Comment: No since the console is being used in the browser. The first one prints HEYYY!! and the second one undefined. You can try it.

Answer (score -1):

Code would definitely help, but it may be an issue with the output rather than the command.

Take for example this code block:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

It runs as expected, but only because the parameter is defined.

An example of something that may yield the same problem is

```
console.log(variable);
```

where `variable` has not yet been defined. If it is a syntax error in red, than this is most likely the issue. If not, your `console.log()` statement may be blank with no parameter.

Comment: var output = []

function fizzBuzz()  {
 
if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
  output.push("FizzBuzz");

if (count % 3 === 0) {

output.push("Fizz");

}
else if (count % 5 === 0) {
  output.push("Buzz")


} else {
 output.push(count);
}
 count++;


 console.log(output);


}
}